# HTML5 Form validation message doesn't show when scroll-behaviour is set to 'smooth' on html tag in Chrome

Tags: html, css, forms, validation, smooth-scrolling

I'm having a conflict when setting the `scroll-behaviour:smooth` attribute on the html tag when there are form fields on the page using HTML5 Validation. You can see this issue when using Chrome (fine in Firefox/Safari)

If the first error field is outside of the viewport then on validation, the document scrolls up and focusses on the field however the error message is not shown.

I've setup the basic code below. Note: this issue doesn't occur when using Codepen, JSFiddle etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Scroll Behaviour / Form validation Issue</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <style>
            html, body {
                scroll-behavior: smooth;
            }

            p {
                margin-bottom: 1200px;
            }
        </style>
      
    </head>

    <body>

        <h3>Scroll behavior / From validation issue</h3>

        <form id="frm-enquiry" action="?">
            <fieldset>

                <label for="first-name">First name</label>
                <input id="first-name" type="text" required />

                <p>Scroll down to submit button and click. If scroll occurs then no error message is shown. <br/>(Note: shows if you hit enter on the field)</p>

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>

            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: I see this situation with both Chrome  94.0.4606.81 and Edge. Although using `scroll-behaviour: auto;` worked, I wish there is a better (real) solution.

Comment: Thanks for you input. I had to switch to using javascript in the end which is a shame, hopefully it gets fixed by the next time I come to use it.

Comment: This bug still exists in chrome 98

Comment: Bug still exists in Chromium 116 (Brave browser)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the Blink rendering engine (used by Chrome-based browsers, Edge and Opera). Here's the bug report:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1245534

It also seems to behave similarly in Safari, though I don't think they have an open bug tracking system.

In Firefox, it seems to behave correctly, but ignores the smooth scroll, simply jumping to the correct spot on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn't happen when you use `scroll-behavior: smooth` only in the `body` tag:

```
<style>
    body {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    p {
        margin-bottom: 1200px;
    }
</style>
```

I think this is a quick fix for your problem.

Comment: The scroll-behavior is also just not applying anymore though in our test, it needs to be on html.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my workaround for this issue. Idea is that when an input fires the "invalid" event, wait for any scrolling to finish and then call `reportValidity` on the form to re-show the validation errors.

```
var invalidTimeout;
var scrollTimeout;
$form.find("input, textarea, select").on("invalid", function () {
    // Multiple elements in the form will likely report being invalid at the same time, so we wait 50ms
    // until they've stopped triggering
    clearTimeout(invalidTimeout);
    invalidTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        // Once the invalid events have stopped, we expect the browser to scroll an element into view
        // Wait until that scrolling has stopped before attempting to trigger the validation again
        var hasScrolled = false;
        function onScroll() {
            hasScrolled = true;
            clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
            scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                // We've finished scrolling after an invalid event, so re-trigger the form validation
                form.reportValidity();
                $(window).off("scroll", onScroll);
            }, 50);
        }

        $(window).on("scroll", onScroll);

        // No scrolling was necessary
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!hasScrolled) {
                clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
                $(window).off("scroll", onScroll);
            }
        }, 20);
    }, 50);
});
```